# Node.js Nginx LetsEncrypt Bad Gateway

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, nginx, lets-encrypt

I'm setting up a Node.js app with nginx and LetsEncrypt.

I set it up, but every time I try to access it, it gives me a 502 Bad Gateway error.

Node.js is not showing ANYTHING, so I figured it's not even accessing the app, checked the nginx log and sow this...

```
2016/02/27 09:12:11 [error] 15706#0: OCSP_basic_verify() failed (SSL: error:27069076:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:signer certificate not found) while requesting certificate status, responder: ocsp.int-x1.letsencrypt.org
2016/02/27 09:12:11 [error] 15706#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 212.121.109.65, server: gamepit.nl, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "gamepit.nl"
2016/02/27 09:12:11 [error] 15706#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 212.121.109.65, server: gamepit.nl, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "gamepit.nl"
2016/02/27 09:12:11 [error] 15706#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 212.121.109.65, server: gamepit.nl, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "gamepit.nl"
2016/02/27 09:12:11 [error] 15706#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 212.121.109.65, server: gamepit.nl, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "gamepit.nl"
```

nginx config:

```
upstream app_gamepit {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

# the nginx server instance
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name gamepit.nl;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/gamepit.log;

    ssl on;
    gzip on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gamepit.nl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/gamepit.nl/privkey.pem;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gamepit.nl/fullchain.pem;

    # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers
    # and much more can be added, see nginx config options
    location / {
      proxy_pass https://app_gamepit/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.gamepit.nl;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://gamepit.nl/$1 permanent;
}
```

Node.js app (very small, since I'm testing...)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/gamepit.nl/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/gamepit.nl/fullchain.pem', 'utf8');
var ca = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/gamepit.nl/chain.pem', 'utf8');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate, ca: ca};

var app = require('express')();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('site call!', req.originalUrl);
        next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send('Hello World');
        res.end();
});

var https = https.createServer(credentials, app);

https.listen(3000,'127.0.0.1',  function() {
        console.log('running!');
});
```

Comment: why are you put keys in both nginx and node?

Comment: Because some tutorials told me so :P
I can check if it makes a difference to do so or not, gimme a bit.

Comment: When I removed the lines about SSL, nginx gave me a SSL protocol error, so NGINX needs to know about the ssl certificates and node.js needs them for encrypting, is what I think :)

Comment: You can put key/crt in nginx and then proxying requests to Node (in plain old http).
I recommend this, coz I think encryption/caching/etc is at some low level than aplication logic :) But I have simple https Node's app which works pretty well without nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem...
There is an issue on [github](https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt/issues/1736#issuecomment-167327236)

instead of

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem;
```

you should use

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
```

I have no idea why, but it now works.

Comment: Because it contains the certificate and the chain back to the CA.